# How to populate multiple 2D-Charts from the same datagridview?

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview

I'm having problem with the population of 2D Charts(polar plot/chart) from the same datagridview. Assuming I have a datagridview filled with data og vant to make three individual plots of this data. The datagridview consists of 15 rows and 4 columns. I need to make a plot for each time the "Theta" column changes, with the x and y values consisting of the two last columns "Phi" and "Ampl(dB)".
I get the out of range error...
Code sample (the logic is inside of a button click):

```
        int rowcount = dataGridView3.RowCount - 1;
        double x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3;
        sizeTheta = (180 / degreeToInt) + 1;
        sizePhi = (360 / degreeToInt2) + 1;
        int rowCounter = sizeTheta * sizePhi;
        //XY
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            y = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            XY_Plot.Series["XY"].Points.AddXY(x, y);
        }
        //XZ
        for (int i = 5; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            x2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            y2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            XZ_Plot.Series["XZ"].Points.AddXY(x2, y2);
        }
        //YZ
        for (int i = 10; i <= 14; i++)
        {
            x3 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            y3 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            YZ_Plot.Series["YZ"].Points.AddXY(x3, y3);
        }
```

[image: DGV]

[image: Charts]

Comment: I suggest settting `AllowUserToAddRows=false`  for the DGV to prevent the empty last row. - _I get the out of range error_ Which line and with which values? Do use the __debugger__ for this kind of error!! - How real are the data you show? The last column seems to have the same value in all rows, no? - Other than that the code looks ok..

Comment: Thank you for the respons. My problem is that the data don't get plotted. This DGV have 5 rows for each change of "Theta", if I change the intervals from 90 to 5, the range of points will go from 5 to 73. So I have to adjust the range of point automaticly.

Comment: The last column in the DGV is just fabricated

Comment: Are the data stored in the DGV or in a DataTable? And what is the problem: some or all data not being plotted or an out of range error?? It is hard to help when we don't see the real code and the real resutl..

Comment: The data is sorted in the DGV. The sample of the code I have added is the only part that is related to charts. The charts come up when I click the button, they don't show anything, thats my problem.

Comment: The range problem is fixed with the help from you're first comment.